# Loop in a menu untill a condition or the exit/log out option is selected

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script where an user can add a new database.

The script needs to check, if the name introduced by the user is valid and after if a database with the same name already exist.

For this I already created 2 functions.

- `is_valid_name` , returns 0 if is valid, 1 if is not valid
- `is_database`, returns 0 if a database with the name introduced by the user exist, and 1 if doesn't exist

I want to offer the user the possibility, in case the name is not valid, or the database already exist, to add a different name or cancel/exit.

I want to do this using a `Menu` with 2 options:

1. Add a new database
2. Exit

The pseudo-code:

-> **A:**

```
echo Add a database
read -r $database   # get the database name from the user
check the entered name - `is_valid_name'
```

Branch 1.

- if the name is not valid,  `is_valid_name` will show the error and return 1
  -> **B:**
- show the Menu with the two options
- if the user select Option 1(Add a new database) go back to **A**(see above in bold)
- if the user select option 2(Exit) exist the script

Branch 2

- if the name is valid check if database exist, `is_database`

  Branch 2.1

  - if database exist show the Menu with the two options, go back to **B**(see above in bold)

  Branch 2.2

  - if database doesn't exist go further and execute other code, like create database, populate database etc

I'm thinking of using a `while do loop` to check if both the name and exist for the database, and get out of the loop if both are ok and continue the code or if user wants to exist.

I don't know how to set(not as syntax) the loop to catch both conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, do not use all-uppercase variable names -- those are generally reserved for system use. (it's not that you can't, it's just bad form). Use lower-case variable names for your user-variables.

While it is not 100% clear what the remainder of your script should do, it looks as if you are trying to build a list without duplicates using `is_entity()` to check whether that `'entity'` already exists and returning `0` if it does or `1` if it does not. That part is clear -- what isn't clear is how to make the explanation of how to do it useful to you for the rest of your script.

Let's look at it this way, to check whether one entity exists, there must be a collection of them somewhere. For bash, an array of them make sense. So to check whether an entity already exists within an array, you can do something similar to:

```
declare -a entity   # declare an empty indexed array to hold entities
logout=0            # a flag to handle your 'logout' entry

## check if first argument in entity array
#  return 0 if it exists, 1 otherwise
is_entity() {

    for i in "${entity[@]}"             # loop over array comparing entries
    do
        [ "$i" = "$1" ] && return 0     # if found, return 0
    done

    return 1    # otherwise return 1
}
```

That provides a simple function to check whether a previous element in your `entity` array is present given the first argument to the function (error handling if no argument is given is left to you)

If you are going to have an array of entities, you will need a way to add them. A second simple `add_entity()` function can call your `is_entity()` function and either `return 0` if the name chosen is already in the array, or if not, just add the new name to the array and display a slightly different menu letting you know that the entity was "Added" instead of "Exists". Something simple like the following will work:

```
## add entity to array
#  return 0 if it exists, 1 otherwise
add_entity () {
    local name

    printf "\nenter name: "     # prompt for new entity name
    read name

    is_entity "$name"           # check if it exists with is_entity
    if [ $? -eq '0' ]
    then
        return 0                # if so, return 0
    else
        entity+=( "$name" )     # otherwise add it to array
    fi

    return 1                    # and return 1
}
```

(**note:** the use of `local` for name which insures the `name` variable is limited to the scope of the function and is unset when the function returns)

The remainder of your script to display either the "Added" menu or your "Exists" menu with the two-choices to either add another (or choose another name) could be implemented with two `case` statements based on the return from `add_entity()`. Essentially you will loop continually until `logout` is chosen, calling `add_entity()` at the beginning of the loop and then using a `case` statement based on the return value to determine which menu to display. An outline of the logic would be something like:

```
while [ "$logout" -eq '0' ]   ## main loop -- loop until logout -ne 0
do
    add_entity      # prompt and check with add_entity/is_entity
    case "$?" in    # filter return with case
        0   )       # if the entered name already existed
        ## Existed Menu
        1   )       # if the entity did not exist, but was added to array
        ## Added Menu
    esac
done
```

In each case, your "Existed" or "Added" Menu could use a simple `select` loop and could be something like the following for you `"Exists"` case:

```
            printf "\nEntity exists - '%s'\n" "${entity[$((${#entity[@]}-1))]}"
            select task in "use another name" "logout"  # display exists menu
            do
                case "$task" in
                "use another name"   )  # select menu matches string
                    break
                    ;;
                "logout"   )
                    logout=1  # set logout flag to break outer loop
                    break;
                    ;;
                ""  )   # warn on invalid input
                    printf "invalid choice\n" >&2
                    ;;
                esac
            done
            ;;
```

To verify the operation and that your entities were collected, you could simply display the contents of the array after you exit the loop, e.g.

```
printf "\nthe entities in the array are:\n"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#entity[@]}; i++))
do
    printf "  entity[%2d] %s\n" "$i" "${entity[i]}"
done
```

Putting all the pieces of the puzzle together, you could handle your logic and display the appropriate menu with a script similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a entity   # declare an empty indexed array to hold entities
logout=0            # a flag to handle your 'logout' entry

## check if first argument in entity array
#  return 0 if it exists, 1 otherwise
is_entity() {

    for i in "${entity[@]}"             # loop over array comparing entries
    do
        [ "$i" = "$1" ] && return 0     # if found, return 0
    done

    return 1    # otherwise return 1
}

## add entity to array
#  return 0 if it exists, 1 otherwise
add_entity () {
    local name

    printf "\nenter name: "     # prompt for new entity name
    read name

    is_entity "$name"           # check if it exists with is_entity
    if [ $? -eq '0' ]
    then
        return 0                # if so, return 0
    else
        entity+=( "$name" )     # otherwise add it to array
    fi

    return 1                    # and return 1
}

while [ "$logout" -eq '0' ]   ## main loop -- loop until logout -ne 0
do
    add_entity      # prompt and check with add_entity/is_entity
    case "$?" in    # filter return with case
        0   )       # if the entered name already existed
            printf "\nEntity exists - '%s'\n" "${entity[$((${#entity[@]}-1))]}"
            select task in "use another name" "logout"  # display exists menu
            do
                case "$task" in
                "use another name"   )  # select menu matches string
                    break
                    ;;
                "logout"   )
                    logout=1  # set logout flag to break outer loop
                    break;
                    ;;
                ""  )   # warn on invalid input
                    printf "invalid choice\n" >&2
                    ;;
                esac
            done
            ;;
        1   )       # if the entity did not exist, but was added to array
            printf "\nEntity added - '%s'\n" "${entity[$((${#entity[@]}-1))]}"
            select task in "Add another" "logout"   # display added menu
            do
                case "$task" in
                "Add another"   )
                    break
                    ;;
                "logout"   )
                    logout=1
                    break
                    ;;
                ""  )
                    printf "invalid choice\n" >&2
                    ;;
                esac
            done
            ;;
    esac
done

printf "\nthe entities in the array are:\n"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#entity[@]}; i++))
do
    printf "  entity[%2d] %s\n" "$i" "${entity[i]}"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the script to verify your menus and provide testing of the scripts response to different inputs, you could do something like:

```
$ bash ~/tmp/entity_exists.sh

enter name: one

Entity added - 'one'
1) Add another
2) logout
#? 1

enter name: one

Entity exists - 'one'
1) use another name
2) logout
#? crud!
invalid choice
#? 1

enter name: two

Entity added - 'two'
1) Add another
2) logout
#? 1

enter name: three

Entity added - 'three'
1) Add another
2) logout
#? 2

the entities in the array are:
  entity[ 0] one
  entity[ 1] two
  entity[ 2] three
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. It was a bit difficult to just tell you how to check `is_entity()` without knowing how you have them stored to begin with, but the logic here can be adapted to any number of different circumstances.

Comment: 'is_entity' I already created it; it is checking if a database/table exists or not; so it is not an array, every time do a check on PostgreSQL server.  An user can add a new database/table. So I check to see if the database/table exist, if exist I tell the user to choose a different name, and check again if exist, or to abandon.  If the user introduced a name for database/table that doesn't exist, I continue with the creation of them and assign ownership to them.

Comment: I got you. The same logic would apply, but instead of checking and adding to an array, you would be checking the result of the database/tables query and then sending an update or create statement back to the server. Also, if postgres is similar to mysql, it provides a batch mode where queries, updates and creations can be sent directly from your script -- which is quite handy. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly something like this will do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function is_entity()
{
    # fill in to do what you want
    printf "%s\n" "$1"
}

while true
do
    echo Add New Entity:
    read -r entity
    if is_entity "$entity"; then
    select TASK in 'Entity exist, use another name' 'Logout'
    do
        case "$REPLY" in
        1)
            continue 2
            ;;
        2)
            printf "Bye\n"
            exit 0
            ;;
        esac
    done
    fi
done
```

Comment: why continue 2? I want the user to choose a new name or logout; if the user choose a name get out of the  loop and continue executing the commands bellow; doesn't continue 2 just jump to second option ?

Comment: You said: `1) TASK -> jump back to is entity`.

Comment: sorry for not being clear; I edited my question, hope is more clear now

Comment: In bash with a `select` loop `TASK` will be set to either `"Entity exist, use another name"` or `"Logout"`. Your `case` statement, as written does not relate to the `select` loop it is enclosed within.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - yes, `TASK` will be set as you describe but `REPLY` will also be set by `select`. Does the script work for you?